# JQuery Datatable doesn't interval reload

Tags: jquery, datatables

i have an jquery Datatables in use and trying to reload the data via interval. I can't succeed, but is this code right?

```
(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "./includes/processing.php",
        method: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#DTResTableList_1').dataTable({
                data: data,
                'paging': false,
                'scrollY': 400,
                'select': true,
                columns:[
                    {'data' : 'col0'},
                    {'data' : 'col1'},
                    {'data' : 'col2'},
                    {'data' : 'col3'},
                    {'data' : 'col4'},
                    {'data' : 'col5'}
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    setInterval( function () {
      table.ajax.reload();
}, 1000 );
});
```

tried to built it separately, but this doesn't let the content load itself.

**SOLVED** by using this code;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#DTResTableList_1').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            url: './includes/processing.php',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType:'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataSrc: ""},
            paging:     false,
            scrollY:    400,
            select:     true,
        'columns': [
            {'data' : 'col0'},
            {'data' : 'col1'},
            {'data' : 'col2'},
            {'data' : 'col3'},
            {'data' : 'col4'},
            {'data' : 'col5'}
        ]
    } );
    setInterval( function () {
    $('#DTResTableList_1').DataTable().ajax.reload( null, false ); // user paging is not reset on reload
}, 5000 );
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below instead.

I suggest calling `setInterval` right after successful DataTables initialization otherwise racing condition could occur.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#DTResTableList_1').DataTable({               
        'ajax': {
            'url': "./includes/processing.php",
            'method': "POST",
            'dataType': 'json',
            'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        'initComplete': function(settings){
            var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );

            setInterval( function () {
                api.ajax.reload();
            }, 1000);
        },
        'paging': false,
        'scrollY': 400,
        'select': true,
        'columns': [
            {'data' : 'col0'},
            {'data' : 'col1'},
            {'data' : 'col2'},
            {'data' : 'col3'},
            {'data' : 'col4'},
            {'data' : 'col5'}
        ]
    });
});
```

Comment: this throws an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null"

Comment: `reload()` only works on an ajaxed dataTable, but otherwise agree. The question is actually adressed in the docs -> https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: @davidkonrad, you're right, OP uses `ajax()` and then supplies data to the DataTables, simplified the code based on your comment.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com there is a problem with this part  `'initComplete' function(settings){
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );
        setInterval( function () {
            api.ajax.reload();
        }, 1000);
    },` it throws an **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function**

Comment: @Cyber, I think you didn't wrap your code in `$(document).ready()` property, see updated code for proper handling of `ready` event.

Comment: @Cyber, there lack a `:` between initComplete and function(settings){